# Replace all instances of a period between 2 sets of repeating characters

Tags: javascript, json, regex, replace

I Have a JSON block of code that I'm being sent by a vendor.  Before I can use it, I have to manipulate all the keys (approx 65) to remove periods or it interfere's with my applications usage.  Trying to use a regex pattern with a JS replace function to replace them with underscores.  Presume I have the following string:

```
JSON_String = '{ "Test.String.One" : "Answer.One" ,  "Test.String.Two" : "Answer.Two" , "Test.String.Three" : "Answer.Three"}';
```

I need a Regex Pattern that will replace all the periods in the keys but not in the values.   So that would be all periods either between { and :   or between , and :

The result when done should look like this:

```
JSON_String = '{ "Test_String_One" : "Answer.One" ,  "Test_String_Two" : "Answer.Two" , "Test_String_Three" : "Answer.Three"}';
```

The application is using a Rhino implementation of Javascript so some things like the \K don't appear to work (unless I did something wrong in my testing).

Anybody who can provide the right search pattern to accomplish this?

I'm not against using a loop if it can't be done in one call.

something like the below would be fine.  I just need to get something working.

```
while (JSON_String.search(/regex/g) != -1)
{
  JSON_String = JSON_String.replace(/regex/g,'_')
}
```

Comment: I can do it but, not using regex. do you want??

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with regex but it may be more complicated than what you need to do. This can easily be accomplished with `Object.keys()` and `.replace()`:

```js
var JSON_String = { "Test.String.One" : "Answer.One" ,  "Test.String.Two" : "Answer.Two" , "Test.String.Three" : "Answer.Three"};

document.querySelectorAll('code')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(JSON_String);

function UnderscoreKeys(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj),
        temp = {};
      
    for(var a = 0, len = keys.length; a < len; a++) {
       temp[keys[a].replace(/\./g, "_")] = obj[keys[a]];
    }
  
    return temp;
}

JSON_String = UnderscoreKeys(JSON_String);

document.querySelectorAll('code')[1].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(JSON_String);
```

```html
<strong>Before:</strong><br />
<pre>
  <code>
  
  </code>
</pre>
<br /><br /><strong>After:</strong><br />
<pre>
  <code>
  
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use.

```
    function underscore(){
     var a = dotted = JSON.parse(JSON_string), underscored = {};
     for(var i in dotted){
          underscored[i.repace(/\./, "_")] = dotted[i];
       }
     return JSON.stringify(underscored)
  }
```